# not able to get Archive link using getArchiveLink() method in azure app service

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to get the archive link from my node js application.This is working fine in my local machine but i am getting error in azure private app service.

`octokit.repos.getArchiveLink({owner:owner,repo:sourceRepoName,archive_format:'zipball',ref:branch})`
on executing this command in azure private app service I am getting the following error:

```
{ Error: Command failed: wmic os get Caption
Access is denied.
at makeError (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\execa\index.js:172:9)
at Function.module.exports.sync (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\execa\index.js:341:15)
at module.exports.release (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\windows-release\index.js:34:24)
at module.exports (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\os-name\index.js:39:18)
at getUserAgentNode (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\universal-user-agent\index.js:6:51)
at restEndpoint (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules@octokit\rest\lib\endpoint\index.js:27:48)
at restRequest (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules@octokit\rest\lib\request\index.js:7:26)
code: 1,
stdout: '',
stderr: 'Access is denied.\r\n',
failed: true,
signal: null,
cmd: 'wmic os get Caption',
timedOut: false }
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your error information, the issue was caused by calling the command `wmic os get Caption` which be prevented by the [Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions of Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions). If try to call the command via Kudu console of your WebApp, the error `Access is denied` will be shown as same as I got as the figure below.

[image]

So if you have to use the current node package for Windows, the only way is using Azure Windows VM instead of Azure WebApps. if not, you can try to deploy your app on Azure WebApps for Linux.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually It was working for me last four months but suddenly its stopped working and now I am getting this error. if its a  permission issue, is it possible to  overcome this restriction since it was working earlier.

Comment: @Riazaskather Could you check your app whether upgrade some node modules version automatically? I don't know your app whether call `wmic` before this error happened.

Comment: whether this restriction on windows command can be resolved from azure end by providing access?

Comment: @Riazaskather There is not any workaround way to break the restriction of Azure WebApp sandbox to get permission.